# How to set up a timer that also checks for an event when running

Tags: android, timer

I am developing a Question answer game. So a Timer is a must. 
I want the timer for 30s. The timer should be running in the UI and when an onclick event like pressing a button occurs , that event should be triggered and the timer should be reset. If the timeout occurs it must display a timeout message and exit.
HELP! Thanks in advance

Comment: Also if you can give the code using android.os.Handler that will be really helpful! thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this is the best way to do that I guess a `CountDownTimer`

```
new CountDownTimer(Totalmiliseconds, interval) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long intervalInMili) {
                tv.setText("second remaining - "+intervalInMili/1000);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                tv.setText("Done!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            }
        }.start();
```

Comment: Thanks that was useful.Timer can be replaced by the android.os.Handler class also right? What is the difference..

Comment: Yes, you can also use Handler also, but Handler is associated with thread, so for perfect timing you should use TimerTask as thread sometimes don't perform upto exact timing.

Comment: Then too you should do some R&D as I am also a newbie to Android.

Comment: that's nonsense! what do you think the Timer class does ? it opens a new thread that can be Daemon or not, I'm using it for timing and yes it has it's disadvantages but so is running on the UI thread that has it's own scheduler and just like a thread can push you back until it's done. you can use Handler or Timer or timerTask whatever you think is best for you, you should probably create portable code and then you can check your options to see which one works best.

Comment: What the hell, what was non-sense in that.

Comment: In the run() method I just want to set the UI to start the countdown and then have the listener set up. I think timertask is appropriate for this. But I am not quite able to set the UI :(

Comment: The timer in the UI must decrement by 1s after every second!

Comment: Yes, you can set the counter on the UI using a textview inside the run method.